# Limit rows fetched when designing a new report

Tags: crystal-reports

Is there a way to limit the number of rows fetched from a table when creating a report with the Report Wizard?

Say I have a table with a million records.  I use the report wizard to select this table and some fields.  Before I can get to the step where I can use the select expert; Crystal Reports fetches everything record to render on the report.  This can take 5 - 10 minutes of just waiting.

Is there some setting to limit how many records can be fetched during design time?  Or is there some other approach?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Record Selection Formula

Here is some reference but you may want to google "Crystal Reports Record Selection Formula"

http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=3826

Answer (score 0):

A simple setting can limit the records!! Here it is, if you're using .Net 1.1 (similar set of options in higher frameworks too!).

**Solution 1:** Right click on the report layout > Reports > **Top N/Sort Group Expert** > Choose Top N in the Dropdown that asks for the type of filtering/ sorting you wish to do > Set the Value of top N (100 for ex.) > Uncheck the option that includes other records. You report will be filtered for only the top N records from the Dataset.

**Solution 2:** Using the Record selection formula where you limit the No. of records on a particular Report/Sub report. Right click on the report layout > Reports > Record Selection Formula > Enter the formula as "**RecordNumber <= N**". That's it. The number of records fetched from the Datasource will be only upto N.

Cheers!